# Why does modifying the left attribute in a div with a specified width cause the viewport to zoom out in mobile Safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Here's an example of this happening:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #menu {
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu" class="max-width"></div>
</body>

<script>
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.style.left = "200px";
  });
</script>

</html>
```

If you click the `menu` div in mobile Safari (which should just move the div right `200px`) it seems to cause the entire viewport to shrink. This doesn't seem to happen in other mobile browsers. You can test it here: http://natecollings.com/mobile-safari.html

Does anyone have a mobile Safari workaround for this?

Here's a gif of it happening:

[image: mobile safari issues]

Comment: Changing the `left` style from `0px` to `200px` won't move the element to the left, it will move the element to the right.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I've updated the post.

Comment: What is the purpose of `float` in an `absolute` positioned element?

Comment: @sabithpocker you're right, the `float` is unnecessary. Just some copypasta, I think. I've removed it from the post (same problem, though).

Comment: can you include a link that we can test in mobile safari?

Comment: works okay on my safari

Comment: @sabithpocker yeah, here's a link: http://natecollings.com/mobile-safari.html

Comment: Can you try adding `top:0` as well?

Comment: Yeah, same issue with `top: 0`. Also, seems like it may be fixed in the newest versions of Safari...at least when I test it with the XCode simulator with an iPhone 5 the problem occurs, but not if I simulate an iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force a `min-width` to be equal to the actual width and `min-height` to be equal to the actual height and try it out on safari on mobile? This might push the browser to use that height and width.

Something like:

```
#menu {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  min-height: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the same problem occurs when using `min-height` and `min-width`.